# Ruby on Rails Installation error on Ubuntu Linux 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting problem while installing rails in Linux. Permission error is coming when i'm trying to run gem install rails.Still i'm getting this error.

Comment: Follow this link: https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04